# Casting from x509 to x5092

Tags: vb.net, casting, x509certificate

I don't know where it thinks I'm casting.

Here is my property

```
''' <summary>
        ''' Gets the GetX509Certificate from a file.
        ''' </summary>
        Private ReadOnly Property GetX509Certificate() As X509Certificate2
            Get
                If m_X509Certificate Is Nothing Then
                    'Should be able to use any of the "Create" methods in the namespace.
                    Dim path As String = "C:\Development\Workspaces\Productivity Framework\V07\Akcelerant.Connector.RouteOne.Web\Test.cer"
                    m_X509Certificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile(path)
                End If
                If m_X509Certificate Is Nothing Then
                    Throw New ApplicationException("Certificate not found")
                End If
                Return m_X509Certificate
            End Get
        End Property
```

and heres where it says im doing the illegal cast:

```
Dim cert As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 = Me.GetX509Certificate
```

Why is it saying that? Everything is defined in the right type but it still thinks I'm casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CreateFromCertFile generates the old object type. Use this method, but then use the X509Certificate2 constructor to cast.

Answer (score 2):

The vb.net code:

```
dim certificatePath as String = "c:\cert.cer"

Dim cert As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certificatePath))
```